# Hitting the wrong button while reviewing

Tags: discussion, review, wrong-answers

Because of my trackpad configuration (tap to click) and my unsteady finger in this late hour of the night, I hit the wrong button while reviewing this non-answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1773201

Of course, I flagged it right away.

My question is: 
I could't find a way to modify my review decision. Is there any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.

All I can suggest is to do exactly what you have done; correct your mistake outside the review system.

If your fingers are unsteady at the late hour you might want to consider stopping for the day as well :-).

Comment: Well, somehow I new it. Subconsciously. ;)